# SSRS Conditional Formatting with 3 Colours

Tags: reporting-services, formatting

Trying to figure out conditional formatting for SSRS/Visual Studio and trying to get the figures to show this as an expression as follows;

Below benchmark needs to be Red

Above but within 5% needs to be Gold

More than 5% above needs to be Green

Benchmark 60%

Year 1   62.2%
Year 2  67.4%
Year 3  43.6%

First time in writing something like this so unsure what the best step is!

```
     =iif("Textbox83" > "Textbox82", "SpringGreen", iif("Textbox83" < "Textbox82", "Red", iif("Textbox83" = "Textbox82" + 0.05,"Gold", "Transparent")))
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things here..

1. Use `SWITCH` rather than nested `IIF`s, it much easier to read and debug.
2. You would normally work against the dataset fields rather than the textboxes displayed on the rendered report. If you do refence the textboxes, you probably have to convert the values to numeric before comparison
3. If you reference an object, either a dataset field or an rendered textbox, you must state the property you want, typical `.Value`

If this was being done against dataset fields you would do something like this

```
=SWITCH (
    Fields!myValue.Value < Fields!Benchmark.Value, "Red",    
    Fields!myValue.Value <= (Fields!Benchmark.Value * 1.05), "Gold",
    Fields!myValue.Value > (Fields!Benchmark.Value * 1.05), "Green",
    True, Nothing
    )
```

Switch stops at the first expression that results in True so the sequence of conditions is important. The final expression pair `True, Nothing` acts like an ELSE and returns nothing (which is the default backgroundcolor property, which appears as transparent)

If you wanted to replicate this using the textboxes (don't unless you really have to!) then it's basically the same but a bit more messy.

```
=SWITCH (
    VAL(ReportItems!TextBox83.Value) < VAL(ReportItems!TextBox82.Value), "Red",    
    VAL(ReportItems!TextBox83.Value) <= (VAL(ReportItems!TextBox82.Value) * 1.05), "Gold",
    VAL(ReportItems!TextBox83.Value) > (VAL(ReportItems!TextBox82.Value) * 1.05), "Green",
    True, Nothing
    )
```

The above is from memory and therefore untested but it should be OK.

Comment: I've tried this however, it has worked on the whole grouped column, not each individual element in the group, is there a way around this? For example,  

                Benchmark  Year 1  Year 2 Year 3
    
Income     60%           62.2% 67.4% 43.6%
Outgoings   50%         52.2% 67.4% 43.6%

Comment: Can you **edit your question** to show your report design and what the output looks like now. Make sure you include details any rowgroups and/or column groups that you have setup. If you can include a sample of raw data from your dataset query that might be helpful too.